# Pass array of objects from JS to ASP.NET controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problem with passing the array of objects as mentioned above.

The code generally works, but when I pass the data only 1st object goes further.

I'm a total noob at .js/JSON parsing and would be grateful for guidance.

Also if you have any data on approach towards dynamic forms/JSON parsing in asp.net mvc that would help. I've been scouting internet for a few days now and can't find solution that has all the things I require.

Thanks!

controller that takes json data:

```
 public ActionResult JsonResult(object[] json)
        {



            TempData["json"] = json;

            return View();
        }
```

javascript taking input data from all elements (also those dynamiclly added):

```
<script>

    $(document).on('submit', '.simple-form', function (e) {
        getValues(this);
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    var getValues = function (currForm) {


        var formData = $(currForm).serializeArray();


        //object Array - all values present, though 
       // each value from a row is stored in other object meaning
       // that row having prop1,prop2,prop3 isnt stored in 1 object,
       // 3 rows generate 9 objects (each has 3 properties)
        console.log(formData);

        //here I try to pass JSON to MVC controller
       '@Url.Action("JsonResult", "Session", new { json = "formData" })';
</script>
```

Comment: Your getting your client side and server side totally confused. The Razor code @Url... is ran on the server before it's sent to the client. Where the JS is ran. So you can't simply pass formData between items like that. You want [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: [This should point you in the right direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). Basically you need to gain a better understaing of what your doing here. This as it stands is totally wrong

Comment: Its unclear what your trying to achieve here. Other that your misunderstanding as @Liam has noted, why are you cancelling a submit and the generating exactly the same value that would have been submitted by using `serializeArray()`? And your `object[] json` would never work - your method needs to be `[HttpPost]` and the parameter needs to be a model.

Comment: Thx Liam. Alr on the task :)

Comment: Stephen it's the aftermath of a lot of changes from the code context; enough to say it's done to override default submit buton function and do this instead - it's tailored for dynamiclly added form elements at the site - if adding the form's code would make my intentions clearer I'll do it

Comment: But using `serializeArray()` just serializes the values of your form control which is exactly what the normal submit sends anyway so its rather pointless unless you want to use ajax so that you stay on the same page

Comment: Stephen when I tried submiting form normally with added controls - it didn't take the ones added dynamicly this required to change the reaction of submit (it does the same thing but in different manner so to speak); in fact I could drop form whatsoever but at that time someone who helped me just changed the code I had and I left it out up till now though I feel I'll have to change it anyway

Comment: @AleksanderDudek (to ping a user start the message as I have done here) That means you not generating the correct name attributes for the dynamically added controls

Comment: Dynamically added inputs into the form should of been submitted, if they we're valid, actually in the form and the names/id's weren't duplicated. Check you HTML is valid. This is sounding increasingly like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/217110)

Comment: @Liam you might be right; I thought my problem was clear from the context provided, but I could've been wrong. Basicly my problem is that I can't make the right json format from just the input values. I thought that I could get around it in controller (and I didn't know how to pass the object Array I recieved, but as Stephen indicated it's because of the model - I have created one but got stuck on json formatting). In this case I should ask how to format the object Array I get back from post? (this also would answer the doubts about doing the serialization Stephen asked)

Comment: Ok, you have two options, fix the underlying issue and forget about json, etc. You could ask another question here i.e. what has gone wrong not why your solution doesn't work or you go down the ajax route. SO prob can't help much here. You'll need to spend some time understanding it yourself